# Cannot open IE through selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, internet-explorer-11, selenium-iedriver

I am trying to run my automation script in IE and have downloaded IE driver and giving that in path but some reason its not opening and getting error

> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session

I am setting path via batch file

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="chromedriver.exe" -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="IEDriverServer.exe"
```

Here is the code creating the `IEDriverInstance`

```
else if (AutomationConstants.BROWSER_TYPE.equalsIgnoreCase("IE")) 
{ 
    Browser ie = new IEBrowser(); 
    System.out.println(ie); 

    try 
    { 
        webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(SeleniumProperties.getHost()), ie.getCapabilities()); 
    } catch (MalformedURLException mue) 
    { 
        LOGGER.error(mue); 
    }
}

private static final String NAME = "IE"; 
private static DesiredCapabilities capabilities; 
static 
{ 
    capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities(); 
    capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer(); 
    capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS); 
    capabilities.setVersion("11"); 
    capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true); 
    capabilities.setCapability("acceptSslCerts", true); 
} 
/** * */ 
public IEBrowser() 
{ 
    super(NAME, capabilities);
}
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: I am setting path via bathc file java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar  -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="chromedriver.exe" -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="IEDriverServer.exe"

Comment: else if (AutomationConstants.BROWSER_TYPE.equalsIgnoreCase("IE")) {
                Browser ie = new IEBrowser();

                System.out.println(ie);

                try {

                    webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(SeleniumProperties.getHost()), ie.getCapabilities());

                } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
                    LOGGER.error(mue);

                }

Comment: private static final String NAME = "IE";
    private static DesiredCapabilities capabilities;

    static {
        capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

        capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
        capabilities.setVersion("11");
        capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
        capabilities.setCapability("acceptSslCerts", true);
       
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    public IEBrowser() {

        super(NAME, capabilities);

Comment: I've added your code to the question. If/when it gets approved you might want to edit it to make some of the structure more clear. I kept it pretty much the same as you had it in your comments. In the future, comments aren't the best place for large blocks of code. Welcome to stack! Hope you can get this resolved

Comment: Thanks somehow I have managed to open IE and run my test with https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver. its working fine and run all test but its failing at one point, its not clicking on date element, and its working fine with chrome and ff, I am using iedriver 2.53.1, shouold I change IE driver?

Answer (score 0):

please try below solution:

To work around the issue, create a `DWORD` value with the name `iexplore.exe` and the
value of 0 in the following key (for 32-bit Windows):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE
```

For 64-bit Windows installations, the following key should be used:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE
```